# Unity Raycast failing to hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, raycasting, normals

I've been working on a school project for some time, and I wanted to create a bouncing projectile. Now, since in the course we mainly learned to use OnTriggerEnter, thats what I've been using instead of a more suitable OnCollisionEnter.

That said, the code actually works fine in some instances, while in others the Raycast doesnt hit it's target, even if it's the exact same object.
Here it's the code I've been using to get the normal of the object and then to turn the projectile into the required direction. This is run in a script called Projectile.cs, as a component of a projectile with Is Trigger checked.

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        ...
        RaycastHit hit;
        Physics.Raycast(transform.position, other.ClosestPoint(transform.position), out hit);
        Vector3 r = Vector3.Reflect(transform.forward, hit.normal);
        transform.forward = r;
        ...
    }
```

I also used to do the Raycast in an if statement, but I deleted it to debug the code.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxsv5.png) is what it looks like when i draw the Raycast in **red**, and the reflected vector in **green**. If I shoot to the ground (in this case a stretched cube) the Raycast doesn't hit, if I shoot to a wall (still a stretched cube) from one side it works just fine, while if I shoot to the other side the Raycast doesnt hit.

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of Raycast function is the direction so it should probably be:

```
other.ClosestPoint(transform.position) - transform.position;
```

or you wanted to use

```
Physics.Linecast(Vector3 startPosition, Vector3 endPosition, out RaycastHit hitInfo);
```

Comment: Yep, the problem was the direction vector, thank you